# Testing wxPython widget without a display

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, pytest, test-coverage

I have this test case:

```
class MyNiftyPanelTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = wx.App()
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None)
        self.sut = SUT(self.frame, -1)

    […]

    def tearDown(self):
        wx.CallAfter(self.frame.Close)
        self.app.MainLoop()
```

Where `SUT` is a class inheriting from `wx.Panel` which does stuff. This works just fine when I run the tests on a console on my X11 display. No windows is shown but clearly things happen.

However, when I run it via tox (whether `tox -r` or using `xvfb-run tox -v -r`), I get the following error:

```
SystemExit: Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly
```

when calling `self.app = wx.App()`.

Using

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(os.getenv('DISPLAY', False) == False,
                    reason="does not run without a DISPLAY")
```

I can skip those tests when running tox without a `DISPLAY` but that means that my CI tool (Jenkins) will always report the wrong test coverage.

*How can I get this test to work on a headless display?*

Comment: You can try [pytest-xvfb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xvfb).

Comment: @phd Well, I feel sheepish now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass `$DISPLAY` env var in `tox.ini` down to the pytest:

```
[testenv]
passenv = DISPLAY
```

Or add to the list if you already have one.